# An always-running thread in Servelts

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, inter-process-communicat

- I need to built a thread/process that is always running, and can be queried through other servelts and JSP pages...
- This thread/process will be dealing with large files, so it will cache file blocks to reduce file accesses (plus some other processing)...
- So, that thread/process will be loaded and waiting for any queries coming, to answer... as long as the server is running.

I though about making a static class common between all the servelt classes, but I found out that will not work (tomcat deals with each new servelt as a totally new program)

So what are the other options I can try??

Comment: Are you talking about distributed caches? Did you look at Terracotta?

Comment: I don't think I need distributed anything... I am only aiming for one machine as a server... I just don't want to load a 20 MB file into memory upon each client http request..

Comment: Why do you need to access this data (file) from different servlets? You can just serve it from one single servlet.

Comment: the idea is that the client only require one or two blocks of this file... so instead of opening the file eachtime, I was kind of thinking of a caching mechanism... Isn't that better?

Comment: Caching is certainly a good approach. But you should rethink your architecture. For example: What do you mean with "waiting for queries to answer..."? Aren't "queries" in general HTTP requests? Why not serve all requests on that file through that servlet? Then you don't need to distribute the data over all your servlets. And still (see my answer below) the `ServletContext` will be a good start to hold that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Use the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagl.html) to access application-wide scope objects.
2. Use a more sophisticated solution, such as [ehcache](http://ehcache.org) to put your data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Other options in addition to the ones proposed by Morritz

1. Inside Tomcat: register a global object accessible by all servlets using the [Global JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)
2. Within the same JVM: start you shared resources (your static class, repository, etc...) and Tomcat programmatically (embedded) using a launcher like [The Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp). You will need to define a small API implemented by your shared resource and usable by your servlets.
3. Distributed accross JVM: memcached, hazelcast, etc...